# How to display different UI for different users on android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Let's say I'm building a certain type of app that's going to be used by two users; A and B. If user A logs into the app, he needs to be able to see only one tab and a wholly different UI layout. When user B logs in, he needs a dashboard kind of UI with 5 different tabs and so on. Can this be achieved without having to write two different apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of these two methods :

1. use [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) a flavor for each type of users.
2. a sharedpreference value you set in login screen depends on a
   specific value that you specified for the user type from where ever you
   get the data from then check if value == user-type show X hide Y.

Comment: Which is the more efficient way from a performance point of view?

Comment: flavors - so in each flavor you'll use all the features you implemented unlike sharedpreference you'll need to check everywhere and a lots of code in a single apk unnecessarily .